# Is there a way to watch any table changes in MySQL workbench and automatically take action upon?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a database shared by two completely separate server applications and those applications cannot communicate with one another at all. Let's say those two applications are called ***A*** and ***B***. Whenever ***A*** updates table in the shared DB, ***B*** should quickly know that there was a change somehow (remember ***A** and ***B*** cannot communicate with each other). Also, I want to avoid using `setInterval` type of approach where I query every *x* seconds. Initially I thought there would be a way to 'watch' changes within MySQL itself but seems like there isn't. What would be the best approach to achieve this? I'm using **Node.js**, **MySQL Workbench**, and **PHP**.

**TDLR:**

I'm trying to find a best way to 'watch' any table changes and trigger action (maybe like http request) whenever change is detected. I'm using MySQL Workbench and Node.js. I really want to avoid using `setInterval` type of approach. Any recommendation?

Comment: You can use triggers on specific tables, I don't know if there's a way to watch for changes in any table.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is just a GUI. It has nothing to do with Node.

Comment: Create an `AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to `INSERT IGNORE` an entry in a processing table. Work through entries in this table.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a Change Data Capture (CDC) feature. In MySQL, the feature is the binary log.

Some tools like [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) are designed to watch and filter the binary log, and transform it into events on a message queue (e.g. Kafka).

Some comments above suggest using triggers, but this is a problematic idea, because triggers fire during a data change, when the transaction for that change is not yet committed. If you try to invoke an http request or any other application action when a trigger fires, then you risk having the action execute even if the data change is subsequently rolled back. This will really confuse people.

Also there isn't a good way to run application actions from triggers. They are for making subordinate data changes, not actions that are outside transaction scope.

Using the binary log as a record of changes is safer, because changes are not written to the binary log until they are committed. Also the binary log contains all changes to all tables.

Whereas with a trigger solution you would have to create three triggers (INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE) for each table. Also MySQL does not support triggers for DDL statements (CREATE, ALTER, DROP, TRUNCATE, etc.).